# Dismount and Mount of social DB, Sync DB and Profile DB on SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, spservices, sql

We need to mount production DB's of user profile service to Dev environment. We have already restored on SQL dev.

Now our intention, how to dismount existing DB's of user profile service and then how to mount new restored Social DB, Sync DB and profile DB for exciting "user profile service" on DEV environment.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this method to setup new UPS using Prod UPS Profile DB in Development:

1. Delete the UPS and keep the databases in Development UPS;
2. Detached the Prod UPS Profile DB from Prod SQL Server;
3. Restore the Prod UPS Profile DB to Development SQL Server;
4. Re-Create the UPS defined all the databases as before, for the
   Profile DB, use Prod UPS Profile DB;
5. Start up the services and IIS reset etc. similar posts for your
   reference:

http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=300

[Restore User Profile Data to another farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38665/restore-user-profile-data-to-another-farm)

[Here are the source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b89ac519-a4a1-4b56-9adf-663d21d851c6/user-profile-service-application-profile-db-restore-to-another-farm-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious)